# How to call lambda passed a parameter in LISP

Tags: lisp, elisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass a lambda expression in Elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357656/how-to-pass-a-lambda-expression-in-elisp)

I have following code:

```
(defun my-map (p l)
  (mapcar (lambda (el) (p el)) l))

(defun test ()
  (my-map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (list 1 2 3)))
```

(It's example - not actual code I tried to write). It complains that it cannot find function p:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function p)
  (p el)
  (lambda (el) (p el))(1)
  mapcar((lambda (el) (p el)) (1 2 3))
  my-map((lambda (x) (x + 1)) (1 2 3))
  test()
  eval((test) nil)
  eval-expression((test) nil)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  recursive-edit()
  debug(error (void-variable test))
  eval(test nil)
  eval-expression(test nil)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil
```

I guess that it treats a `p` as symbol and not variable bounded in outer scope. How to make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a lambda expression in Elisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357656/how-to-pass-a-lambda-expression-in-elisp) and [How do I pass a function as a parameter to in elisp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213267/how-do-i-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-to-in-elisp)

Comment: @phils: You're right (I voted to close - strange I assumed that author can close it's own question as duplicate).

Comment: This might also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942675/in-elisp-how-do-i-put-a-function-in-a-variable/9943606#9943606

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use `funcall`.

> funcall is a built-in function in `C source code'.
>
> (funcall FUNCTION &rest ARGUMENTS)
>
> Call first argument as a function, passing remaining arguments to it.
>   Return the value that function returns. Thus, (funcall 'cons 'x 'y)
>   returns (x . y).